# Inserting HTML-text to div created before with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating popups in a Leaflet map. The popup content should be created dynamically using javascript. On adding content to a div-container inside the popup with `innerHTML`, I get the error message: "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

Here is my code:

```
//create div for form element "Baumpatenschaft"
var div_baumpatenschaft = document.createElement('div');

//add div_baumpatenschaft to DOM (child of <div> with id="formular")
formular.appendChild(div_baumpatenschaft);

//create ID for div
div_baumpatenschaft.id = "div_baumpatenschaft";

var pt = document.getElementById("div_baumpatenschaft");    

//HTML code for creating radio buttons stored in var baumpatenschaft
var baumpatenschaft = 
      '<label for="radio_ja">ja</label><br/>\
      <input checked="checked" type="radio" name="baumpatenschaft" id="radio_ja" value="ja"/>\
      <label for="radio_nein">nein</label><br/>\
      <input type="radio" name="baumpatenschaft" id="radio_nein" value="nein"/>';


//adding the HTML-code to div_baumpatenschaft
pt.innerHTML = baumpatenschaft;
```

Apparently the div_baumpatenschaft isn't created yet, as innerHTML tries to insert the HTML-code inside the `<div>`.

I have also tried `element.insertAdjacentHTML()` with the same error.

What am I doing wrong? 
Is there another possibility to get around that issue? I definitely want to create the div with `document.createElement('div')` and I also want to define the radio buttons as HTML-text stored in a variable and not with `document.createElement('input')`, what I have done before.

Comment: You created your element but you did not add it to your document. That's why document.getElementById returned null.

Comment: Use `div_baumpatenschaft` for the `.innerHTML` part and add it to the DOM with `.appendChild()`

Comment: I think you should use div_baumpatenschaft.setAttribute('id',"div_baumpatenschaft");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the ***created element*** is not part of the document. You can append the ***created element*** into the *body* before accessing that like the following way:

```
document.body.appendChild(div_baumpatenschaft);
```

```js
//create div for form element "Baumpatenschaft"
var div_baumpatenschaft = document.createElement('div');

//create ID for div
div_baumpatenschaft.id = "div_baumpatenschaft";

document.body.appendChild(div_baumpatenschaft);

var pt = document.getElementById("div_baumpatenschaft");    

//HTML code for creating radio buttons stored in var baumpatenschaft
var baumpatenschaft = 
      '<label for="radio_ja">ja</label><br/>\
      <input checked="checked" type="radio" name="baumpatenschaft" id="radio_ja" value="ja"/>\
      <label for="radio_nein">nein</label><br/>\
      <input type="radio" name="baumpatenschaft" id="radio_nein" value="nein"/>';


//adding the HTML-code to div_baumpatenschaft
pt.innerHTML = baumpatenschaft;
```

**Update:**

```js
//create div for form element "Baumpatenschaft"
var div_baumpatenschaft = document.createElement('div');

//add div_baumpatenschaft to DOM (child of <div> with id="formular")
var formular = document.getElementById('formular');
formular.appendChild(div_baumpatenschaft);

//create ID for div
div_baumpatenschaft.id = "div_baumpatenschaft";

var pt = document.getElementById("div_baumpatenschaft");    

//HTML code for creating radio buttons stored in var baumpatenschaft
var baumpatenschaft = 
      '<label for="radio_ja">ja</label><br/>\
      <input checked="checked" type="radio" name="baumpatenschaft" id="radio_ja" value="ja"/>\
      <label for="radio_nein">nein</label><br/>\
      <input type="radio" name="baumpatenschaft" id="radio_nein" value="nein"/>';


//adding the HTML-code to div_baumpatenschaft
pt.innerHTML = baumpatenschaft;
```

```html
<div id="formular"></div>
```

Comment: Create an element, add it to the DOM, let the browser find it again, change its content. There's room for improvement...

Comment: I missed to post the line with appendChild() in my sample here. I did this in my code, but still with an error message. The solution was, as @Andreas mentioned, to use div_baumpatenschaft.innerHTML() and not pt.innerHTML(). Now it works. Why does innerHTML() not accept document.getElementById("div_baumpatenschaft") stored in a variable?

Comment: @pascatl It does. But the error (_"... of null"_) indicates that the element isn't part of the DOM yet when you call `document.getElementById(...)`.

Comment: @pascatl, `innerHTML` is a property not method, you can assign the property like `innerHTML = ....`

Comment: @pascatl _"I missed to post the line with appendChild() in my sample here."_ - The please adjust your question accordingly (for future readers).

Comment: Question adjusted. But still only working by using div_baumpatenschaft and not the variable pt on ```innerHTML```

Comment: @pascatl, the added second answer shows that your code is working if you have the element with `id=formular`....

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think I'm struggling understanding my own code. As I see, in theory it should work.